# Testing program using fgets() automatically

Tags: c, fgets

I'm currently working on a bash-like project. However, I need to test this project with several thousands tests, what cannot be checked manually. That's why I'd like to perform the tests automatically.

My program used `fgets()` to get user input. I know how to send arguments to program directly, but when the program is started, it displays the prompt of the program. How to *cat* a file containing tests on the stdin to make the program able to interpret tests? (and get the program output in the terminal).

Comment: `program < testfile`? Or do you want to hide the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your test input is stored in a file called "test.input" (with each line being the complete input to the program)  you can do the following in bash:

```
export LINE_NO=0
cat test.input | while read LINE; do echo "$LINE" | ./program > results.$LINE_NO;
   LINE_NO=$(($LINE_NO + 1));
done
```

Basically, for each line in test.input, the above command will feed it to the program and store the results of the program in results.0, results.1, results.2, etc, where the number in results.number is the line number of the test.input file.

Hope this helps.